# Undefined Constant in PHP

Tags: php, sql

We are getting a couple of notices in prestashop when customers add products to cart, namely the following:

> Impossible to add the product to the cart.
>       textStatus: 'parsererror'
>       errorThrown: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'
>       responseText:
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant id_customization_field_width - assumed 
>       'id_customization_field_width' in 
>       /home/public_html/override/controllers/front/CartController.php 
>       on line 83
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant id_customization_field_height - assumed 
>       'id_customization_field_height' in 
>       /home/public_html/override/controllers/front/CartController.php 
>       on line 83

The code (line 83) which this refers to is as follows:

```
/*add new customization cart*/
$id_customization = 0;
if ($this->_newCustomization && id_customization_field_width && id_customization_field_height) {
   if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {
       $id_adv = $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery;
   } else {
       $id_adv = 0;
   }
```

Can anyone help with this? We can't seem to find where the issue lies.

Comment: change `id_customization_field_height ` to `$id_customization_field_height`...do the same with `id_customization_field_width`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

what is:
id_customization_field_width 
and
id_customization_field_height

is it possible that it is:

```
$id_customization_field_width && $id_customization_field_height
```

or

```
$this->id_customization_field_width && $this->id_customization_field_height
```

?